# Amortization schedule for many rows using Excel Macro

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to Excel VBA and looking for help in editing a macro.

I have three columns Sanctioned Amount, Tenure and Rate of Interest for 7328 rows.

[Data Looks something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pwSn5.jpg)

I already have a working VBA script(given below) to calculate the amortization schedule but I want it to take the inputs from the 3 columns, calculate it for 7328 rows(instead of manually putting it in) and append the values below each other.

I am requesting changing the script below to take the values from 3 columns.

```
Sub one()

Dim intRate, loanLife, initLoan, payment As Double
Dim yearBegBal, intComp, prinComp, yearEndBal, intTot, prinTot, fvloan As Currency

ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Delete

intRateYrs = InputBox("Input Interest rate (Annual):")
loanLifeYrs = InputBox("Input Loan life (Years):")
initLoan = InputBox("Input Loan amount:")

Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

intRateMths = (intRateYrs / 100) / 12
loanLifeMths = loanLifeYrs * 12

Cells(4, 2).Value = Format(intRateYrs, "#.##") & " %"
Cells(4, 3).Value = Format(intRateMths, "Percent")
Cells(5, 2).Value = loanLifeYrs
Cells(5, 3).Value = loanLifeMths
Cells(6, 2).Value = Format(initLoan, "Currency")

payment = Pmt(intRateMths, loanLifeMths, -initLoan)
Cells(7, 2).Value = Format(payment, "Currency")

outRow = 10
intTot = 0
prinTot = 0
fvloan = 0

Cells(10, 2).Value = "Beginning Balance"
Cells(10, 3).Value = "Payment"
Cells(10, 4).Value = "Interest"
Cells(10, 5).Value = "Principal"
Cells(10, 6).Value = "End Balance"
Cells(10, 7).Value = "Total Interest"
Cells(10, 8).Value = "Total Principal"
Cells(10, 9).Value = "Total Repaid"
yearBegBal = initLoan

For rowNum = 1 To loanLifeMths
    intComp = yearBegBal * intRateMths
    prinComp = payment - intComp
    yearEndBal = yearBegBal - prinComp

    intTot = intTot + intComp
    prinTot = prinTot + prinComp
    fvloan = intTot + prinTot

    Cells(outRow + rowNum, 1).Value = rowNum
    Cells(outRow + rowNum, 2).Value = Format(yearBegBal, "Currency")
    Cells(outRow + rowNum, 3).Value = Format(payment, "Currency")
    Cells(outRow + rowNum, 4).Value = Format(intComp, "Currency")
    Cells(outRow + rowNum, 5).Value = Format(prinComp, "Currency")
    Cells(outRow + rowNum, 6).Value = Format(yearEndBal, "Currency")
    Cells(outRow + rowNum, 7).Value = Format(intTot, "Currency")
    Cells(outRow + rowNum, 8).Value = Format(prinTot, "Currency")
    Cells(outRow + rowNum, 9).Value = Format(fvloan, "Currency")

    yearBegBal = yearEndBal
Next rowNum

ActiveSheet.Range("A:I").EntireColumn.AutoFit
Rows("11:11").Select
ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True
Range("A1").Select

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False


End Sub
```

[This is how result look like from one iteration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Cj1K.jpg)

Comment: Add a sample of your Data.

Comment: @SivaprasathVadivel I have added a sample of the data in the image

Comment: You have input boxes for the values....you can just loop through the rows and populate the variable from the cell values and get the calculation. Please add the desired output for the sample data you have provided also. For reference

Comment: @SivaprasathVadivel I dont know how to replace text boxes with input values by using loops..thats why I am looking for help.. I have added result from the script that I have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub one()

Dim intRate, loanLife, initLoan, payment As Double
Dim yearBegBal, intComp, prinComp, yearEndBal, intTot, prinTot, fvloan As Currency
Dim cell As Range


For Each cell In ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("B2:B2001")

    'intRateYrs = InputBox("Input Interest rate (Annual):")
    'loanLifeYrs = InputBox("Input Loan life (Years):")
    'initLoan = InputBox("Input Loan amount:")

    intRateYrs = cell.Offset(0, 1).Value
    loanLifeYrs = cell.Value
    initLoan = cell.Offset(0, 2).Value

    lrow = Sheets(2).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    intRateMths = (intRateYrs / 100) / 12
    loanLifeMths = loanLifeYrs * 12
    With Sheets(2)
    Cells(lrow + 4, 2).Value = Format(intRateYrs, "#.##") & " %"
    Cells(lrow + 4, 3).Value = Format(intRateMths, "Percent")
    Cells(lrow + 5, 2).Value = loanLifeYrs
    Cells(lrow + 5, 3).Value = loanLifeMths
    Cells(lrow + 6, 2).Value = Format(initLoan, "Currency")

    payment = Pmt(intRateMths, loanLifeMths, -initLoan)
    Cells(lrow + 7, 2).Value = Format(payment, "Currency")

    outRow = lrow + 10
    intTot = 0
    prinTot = 0
    fvloan = 0

    Cells(lrow + 10, 2).Value = "Beginning Balance"
    Cells(lrow + 10, 3).Value = "Payment"
    Cells(lrow + 10, 4).Value = "Interest"
    Cells(lrow + 10, 5).Value = "Principal"
    Cells(lrow + 10, 6).Value = "End Balance"
    Cells(lrow + 10, 7).Value = "Total Interest"
    Cells(lrow + 10, 8).Value = "Total Principal"
    Cells(lrow + 10, 9).Value = "Total Repaid"
    yearBegBal = initLoan

    For rowNum = 1 To loanLifeMths
        intComp = yearBegBal * intRateMths
        prinComp = payment - intComp
        yearEndBal = yearBegBal - prinComp

        intTot = intTot + intComp
        prinTot = prinTot + prinComp
        fvloan = intTot + prinTot

        Cells(outRow + rowNum, 1).Value = rowNum
        Cells(outRow + rowNum, 2).Value = Format(yearBegBal, "Currency")
        Cells(outRow + rowNum, 3).Value = Format(payment, "Currency")
        Cells(outRow + rowNum, 4).Value = Format(intComp, "Currency")
        Cells(outRow + rowNum, 5).Value = Format(prinComp, "Currency")
        Cells(outRow + rowNum, 6).Value = Format(yearEndBal, "Currency")
        Cells(outRow + rowNum, 7).Value = Format(intTot, "Currency")
        Cells(outRow + rowNum, 8).Value = Format(prinTot, "Currency")
        Cells(outRow + rowNum, 9).Value = Format(fvloan, "Currency")

        yearBegBal = yearEndBal
    Next rowNum

    ActiveSheet.Range("A:I").EntireColumn.AutoFit
    Rows("11:11").Select
    ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True
    Range("A1").Select
    End With
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Next cell

End Sub
```

Comment: I tried running the script just for Range B2:B7 but its still throwing an error "Subscript out of range"

Comment: if you are running the code in the same workbook...try thisworkbook.sheets(1).range("B2:B7328").

Comment: ran with ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).range("B2:B2001") Its still giving the same error "Subscript out of range"

Comment: Does your workbook have a sheet1 and is the columns B,C,D are there?

Comment: Yes it had B,C,D. Actually I needed to create Sheet(2) before code is run. I did that it ran. Thanks a lot. I will paste complete code in case in future some one else wants it